# opencv installation ffmpeg error

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ffmpeg

I have been trying to install opencv for a long time in my fedora 20 32 bit system.I followed the instructions from http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html#install-opencv-python-in-fedora 
But after all cmake commands when I m trying to make it I am getting an error again and again.

```
    scanning dependencies of target opencv_createsamples
     [100%] Building CXX object    apps/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/createsamples.cpp.o
    Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_createsamples
   /lib/libavcodec.so.55: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_dx_algo'
    /lib/libavcodec.so.55: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_cx_algo'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_createsamples] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [apps/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have followed so many articles about the ffmpeg versions and updating stuff but did understand a little. but when I tried

```
$ sudo yum update ffmpeg
```

I got the error as

```
>Package(s) ffmpeg available, but not installed.
No packages marked for update
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link on the subject of linking OpenCV to FFmpeg on Linux:
[How to install FFmpeg & OpenCV under Fedora Linux](https://sites.google.com/a/asu.edu/wireless-video-sensor/how-to-1/how-to-install-ffmpeg-opencv-under-fedora)

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem on fedora 19 (32-bit) on vmware
I update the machin
 `yum update`
After that I loged out and reboot the machin and try to `make` agin, and it works!:] 
Now on python I successfully accomplish the `import cv2`